# File.dirname windows path returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I want to extract the directory name from a windows path. The windows path is a string, something like the following:

```
"c:\\some\path\name"
```

when I do the following:

```
File.dirname("c:\\some\\path\\name")
```

The result is

```
"."
```

If I run this on the unix path it works fine

```
File.dirname("/some/path/name") => "/some/path"
```

Do I need to somehow set the `FILE::ALT_SEPARATOR`? I have tried different variations of the path to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to replace all the backslashes with a forward slash. This works decently well. However there still must be a better solution.

```
File.dirname("c:\\some\\path\\name".gsub('\\', '/')).gsub('/', '\\')
=> "c:\\some\\path"
```

I sub the backslashes back in after the dirname call in order to keep the representation consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to always use unix-type forward slash for path separators in Ruby code. Even if you use it on Windows OS, they will be correctly mapped internally to its backslash path separators.

If the backslash comes from the user input, then you need to detect whether the OS is such that allows a backslash in a file name (e.g., Windows does not, Unix does). Then if the backslash is not allowed, then you should convert them to forward slash during validation. In the Ruby code, keep all separators as forward slash. So, you should not be caring about backslashes when using commands such as `File.dirname`.

Comment: Users will specify the path. Should I make allowances for the backslash input and convert all to forwardslashes?